# Default the year based on month value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query to display the year value from a table and default the current year.

```
select distinct year(startdate) as syear, year(startdate) as eyear, 1 as sOrder from [TTS].[dbo].[Class] where year(startdate) <> year(getdate())
    union all
    select year(getdate()) as syear, year(getdate()) as eyear, 0 as sOrder
    order by sOrder asc, syear desc
```

[image]

Here default year is  2015 (with Sorder 0) . Now I Need to display the Default Year based on month value. For e.g if year is 2015 and months are in jan,feb,mar,april then default year is 2015. else default year is 2016.  i have tried the below query

```
select distinct year(startdate) as syear, year(startdate) as eyear, 1 as sOrder  from [TTS].[dbo].[Class]  where
 year(startdate) <> year(getdate())
union all
select year(getdate())+1 as syear, year(getdate())+1 as eyear, 0 as sOrder where month(getdate()) not in(1,2,3,4) 
union all
select year(getdate()) as syear, year(getdate()) as eyear, 0 as sOrder where month(getdate())in(1,2,3,4)

order by sOrder asc, syear desc
```

But year values are getting duplicated. can any help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server is correct in what it's doing as you are requesting an additional row to be returned which if ran now 2015-06-22 would return "2016"
Your distinct only works on the first select you've done so these are your options:

1) Use cte's with distincts

```
with subq1 (syear, eyear, sOrder) as (select year(getdate())+1 as syear, year(getdate())+1 as eyear, 0 as sOrder where month(getdate()) not in(1,2,3,4) 
union all
select year(getdate()) as syear, year(getdate()) as eyear, 0 as sOrder where month(getdate())in(1,2,3,4)),
subq2 as (select distinct year(startdate) as syear, year(startdate) as eyear, 1 as sOrder  from [TTS].[dbo].[Class])

Select distinct syear, eyear, sOrder
from subq1
UNION ALL
select syear, eyear, sOrder
from subq2 s2
where s2.syear <> (select syear from subq1)

order by sOrder asc, syear desc
```

SQL Fiddle for this can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f89b3a/3/0

2) You could try use a grouping:

```
select distinct syear, eyear, min(sOrder)
from
(select distinct year(startdate) as syear, year(startdate) as eyear, 1 as sOrder 
from [TTS].[dbo].[Class]
union all
select year(getdate())+1 as syear, year(getdate())+1 as eyear, 0 as sOrder where month(getdate()) not in(1,2,3,4) 
union all
select year(getdate()) as syear, year(getdate()) as eyear, 0 as sOrder where month(getdate())in(1,2,3,4)) subq

Group by syear, eyear
order by min(sOrder) asc, syear desc
```

SQL Fiddle for this can be found here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f89b3a/5/0

I personally would recommend option 1 over option 2.

Comment: I tried out your suggesion 1 . but i get  duplicated result.                    syear eyear sOrder
2016 2016 0
2016 2016 1
2014 2014 1
2013 2013 1
2012 2012 1
2011 2011 1
2010 2010 1
2009 2009 1
2008 2008 1
1900 1900 1                             .                                                  In the second row 2015 need to be there instead of 2016. any way to do that?

Comment: Do they have different sOrder's by any chance?

Comment: for the default year it is 0 otherwise 1

Comment: You must have a startdate that is in 2016 which is what is causing the issue.

Comment: Mixed up my tables, it should work with the updated now.

Comment: SQL Fiddles for both options have now been added to the answer

Comment: almost there but 2015 is missed from output :(. (2015 should come with sorder 1)

Comment: @BaijuMohan did the updated code work for you? There are SQL Fiddles attached to both to display how they work.

Comment: Thanks! Updated code works fine. Appreciate your help.

Comment: No worries, if you're happy with the answer then you can accept it if you like so others will know it has been answered and you can gain reputation too

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code (where you tried to find the current year) with the below one should work.

```
SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(MM,-4,GETDATE())) + 1

like 


SELECT DISTINCT year(startdate) AS syear
    ,year(startdate) AS eyear
    ,1 AS sOrder
FROM [TTS].[dbo].[Class]
WHERE year(startdate) <> year(getdate())

UNION ALL

SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(MM, - 4, GETDATE())) + 1 AS syear
    ,YEAR(DATEADD(MM, - 4, GETDATE())) + 1 AS eyear
    ,0 AS sOrder
ORDER BY sOrder ASC
    ,syear DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` to exclude duplicates:

```
SELECT  YEAR(startdate) AS syear ,
        YEAR(startdate) AS eyear ,
        1 AS sOrder
FROM    [TTS].[dbo].[Class]
WHERE   YEAR(startdate) <> YEAR(GETDATE())
UNION
SELECT  YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1 AS syear ,
        YEAR(GETDATE()) + 1 AS eyear ,
        0 AS sOrder
WHERE   MONTH(GETDATE()) NOT IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
UNION
SELECT  YEAR(GETDATE()) AS syear ,
        YEAR(GETDATE()) AS eyear ,
        0 AS sOrder
WHERE   MONTH(GETDATE()) IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
ORDER BY sOrder ASC ,
        syear DESC
```